# How to find L1, L1i, L1d cache from dmidecode output?

Tags: memory, hardware, cache, dmidecode

- How to find L1 , L1d, L1i cache from dmidecode output ?

(NOTE: `dmidecode` file is from different server for which I do not have access, So I can not run `lscpu` command to find the same)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
cat dmi.txt | grep -i core
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Handle 0x0700, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: Not Specified
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1  <------------  
        Operational Mode: Write Back
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 32 kB  <---------------------------
        Maximum Size: 32 kB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Unknown
        Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Error Correction Type: None
        System Type: Data
        Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0701, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
        Socket Designation: Not Specified
        Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
        Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
        Location: Internal
        Installed Size: 2048 kB
        Maximum Size: 2048 kB
        Supported SRAM Types:
                Pipeline Burst
        Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
        Speed: 15 ns
        Error Correction Type: None
        System Type: Unified
        Associativity: Other
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Or is there any more information do i need to check ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have information about L1, L1d & L1i cache from dmidecode. Its just gives you the total L1 L2 & L3 cache information.

lscpu is a neat command to give you the cache information.

```
lscpu|grep cache
```

You can also have more information in /sys/devices/system/cpu/